# nstimer in android

Tags: android

dear ,how to use nstimer in android as in iphone...for refresh the url on every time intervell...or i use TIMER.SCHEDULE() for ping the server on each time intervall
thanks in advance..

Comment: Can you tell me what did you use to solve this problem, or can you accept any answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For tasks where you would use NSTimer on iOS, Android's [Handler class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) for tasks like this.